# Anti-virus evasion testing: using VM with AVs to test payload detection

Tags: malware, exploit, antivirus

Using a tool like veil or hyperion to evade an AV for pentesting, it's not advised to upload to virus total because it increases detection rate (and/or gets some special attentions). My understanding is that if you upload to Virus Total, there's a good chance your payload/ its signature could end up in AV databases.

That said, if you don't know what AV you're going to need to evade, is it appropriate to do the following:

- buy a subscription to say, the x most popular AVs
- install them in a VM
- update so they have the most recent database
- shut off any network connections (so it can't report back the payload)
- Scan our payload

1) Would this prevent the payload from ending up in a an AV DB / getting detected?

2) Is there a better way of doing this? I know Virus Total allows you to check hashes but there must be other heuristics that AVs use.

3) If not, is there a VM or tool someone has made to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: If you are pen testing then why not target your target(s) specifically? I would VMware Converter the target Windows endpoint or Windows Server and analyze those images before testing in a lab (Host-only, like you mention). Before wrapping (e.g., Veil, Hyperion), you may just want to try a stageless meterpreter DLL in Paranoid mode with multiple transports in the lab, and if works -- then go prod. If you have to wrap, go with ShellterProject -- it's in Kali Linux. Test out your post scripts as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I believe I've come to an answer. I may need to clarify my question but in a nut shell what I'm looking to do is this: I'd like to be able to test my payload against as many anti-virus engines/databases as possible. Normally I'd do this with virus total, but I'm told that if you upload a sample it increases the likelihood that my payload will become detected. In other words, samples uploaded to VT get some "special attention" and thus most tools discourage users from uploading.

My solution is to scan my sample/payload with VMs containing various anti-virus softwares. In my search I found a tool that does just this. That is, it's an open source Virus Total which I as a user retain complete control over.

Meet [Malice](https://github.com/maliceio/malice/). Malice works by spinning up docker containers which contain various AVs. Most of them are free but you can also provide product keys for AVs that have paid subscriptions. This is exactly what I was looking for. I can now run a command like `malice scan sketchy.exe` and it will scan against the default AV engines. While not as complete as Virus total, this is definitely good enough. Really a cool project, I hope it continues to under go active development.

While this does answer my question, someone might know of a better solution so I'm going to wait at least a few days to accept my own answer.

As @atdre mentioned, there are many other such tools.
opswat.com/solutions/multi-scanning
irma.quarkslab.com/overview.html
github.com/PlagueScanner/PlagueScanner
github.com/joxeankoret/multiav
herdprotect.com

Comment: Looked at Malice a few times. It's good, but I think your question is sort of jacked in the first place. Why even use a PE payload? And if so, why not an MSIL PE payload? If your goal is to evade AV for pentesting then what about other controls -- other protections? Why not -- https://github.com/Arno0x/DBC2 -- https://github.com/nettitude/PoshC2 -- or -- https://cobbr.io/ObfuscatedEmpire.html -- ?

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways to test payload detection, including ways to upload variations of your payload to VirusTotal.

If you want to upload to VirusTotal, consider using [Recomposer](https://github.com/secretsquirrel/recomposer) to change a little what you are doing (and provide those variations).

If you are looking for more-advanced payloads, check out this resource -- https://github.com/nccgroup/Winpayloads -- or the ones mentioned in my comment to the original question above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Those are definitely good suggestions and you've taught me a few new methods and suggested some tools I'll be looking into. However, I'm really interested in testing a payload against as many AV databases/engines as possible to establish that my payload is flying under the radar. This for the situation wherein I don't know I don't know what AV that a target might be using. I should mention that I'm not a professional pen-tester. I'm looking to get into the industry and satisfy curiosity. If my approach is misguided, let me know. Thanks again!

Comment: There's tons of projects, commercial and open-source, that do what you are asking for, but I don't recommend them! -- https://www.opswat.com/solutions/multi-scanning -- http://irma.quarkslab.com/overview.html -- https://github.com/PlagueScanner/PlagueScanner -- http://github.com/joxeankoret/multiav -- http://www.herdprotect.com

Comment: Thank you! Why wouldn't you recommend them?

Answer (score 0):

In an attempt to complete the above answers and add some more resources, i will also propose using yara rules. There are many tools out there, such as [loki](https://github.com/Neo23x0/Loki) which use yara rules to detect many sorts of malware. They have a huge list of signatures from well-known anti-viruses and some custom ones. Apart from this tool, I generally propose yara rules for reckoning malicious files.

For different sort of analysis, you can set up locally a [Cuckoo Sandbox](https://cuckoosandbox.org/), or use directly their online platform.

My general suggestion is to find and set up or create some tools that will be able to run locally (vms, scripts, containers etc), so you can be sure of their actions and of the fact they won't be sending data, exposing your artifacts.

Happy hunting!